# PhD student I am working with as an undergrad may pursue something similar to what my senior thesis is on, is this a conflict of interest?

Tags: thesis, etiquette, computer-science, research-undergraduate, conflict-of-interest

I began researching for my thesis on subject *X* several months ago, and the thesis program is starting in a few weeks.

I did not tell the grad student at the old uni about this yet - because originally we were working on different things, his idea seemed cool, and naturally, I want my name on as many papers as possible. However, my adviser told me that my research idea may be enough to be considered a significant contribution in the field. A lot of people in research are interested in how *X* can be applied to different areas right now, but my idea on how to apply it is completely my own and unique.

I feel I should either only work on my thesis at my new uni, or email the grad student at my old one, let him know I am researching X right now, and that if he involves X in his research, that might not look good for me.

How should I go about this? I feel bad because the grad student invested time into teaching me for the last 4 weeks and getting me caught up, but I also want to do what's best for me - which is 100% pursuing my research idea.
The fact that my adviser thinks it is publishable and may make an impact in the field is rare enough in undergrad, while the grad student I am working with is not sure what exactly he's researching yet - and I fear that he will look into using X now, which might cross with my research.

Comment: Something confusing: in the earlier part, you say that the other method was/is X, and yours is Y. But then later you seem to indicate that your method is _also_ X. Can you clarify?

Comment: Unless you made a mistake in writing, you decided to pursue X, which the graduate student was working on, after this presentation and a whole discussion on X, and the interest it receives? But you came up with a different way to apply X? Is that it?

Comment: Surely though, you developed this idea through exchanges with this graduate student. I think the high way to take is to collaborate on a paper, with you as the first author if it is indeed a novel way of applying X.

Comment: I don't think I explained well enough and confused myself generalizing. So I have worked with 2 grad students at my old uni. One asked me to do something for him, while reading papers for that, this inspired a whole new idea. I actually did ask him his opinion but he switched to a different research area and left the school.

Comment: I had my idea on X BEFORE the presentation. Yes, some UG are actually good at coming up with ideas - I know how rare it is, but I am an older student. He didn't even know I was pursuing it for my senior thesis. All of the sudden, it seems like he is interested in this area as well.

Comment: the grad student was not working on X, I guess I failed to word this correctly

Comment: From my reading, there is nothing wrong with what you are doing.  You can develop idea X on your own.  You should also familiarize yourself with the rules of co-authorship.  Australian universities follow the "Australian Code for the Responsible Conduct of Research" for example.

Comment: I simply don't understand the scenario. As far as I understand you seems to moved idea(s) from a PhD person / group / institution to your master thesis / new group / new institution. This won't be conflict of interest but it can be some sort of appropriation. To tell you if it is indeed the case one should know the scenario in details. The new supervisor might want to know it as well.

Comment: You don't gain ownership over an area of research by working in it. Issues arise when someone takes your ideas and misattributes them.

Answer (score 2):

No.  One of the criteria for a problematic conflict of interest is that the conflicted person has power.  The PhD student does not have any power in this situation.

In general, collaboration is good.